# how to install openstack client for windows

Tags: openstack

i have a windows machine where I need to run openstak client. I have installed python 2.7.13 , but when I try installing "pip install python-openstackclient" I am getting below error.

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-openstackclien
 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-openstackclient
```

Can anyone help me to correct the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I run openstack   CLI in windows under python 3.5.2  to execute use  MINGW64 which comes with Git Bash

Answer (score 0):

1. First install python 3
2. Run

   pip install python-openstackclient

Note: Working on windows 10

Comment: In the question, they say they tried running "pip install python-openstackclient", and received an error. As such, this doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

By OpenStack client do you mean OpenStack compute? The controller node needs to be installed on a Linux machine. HyperV on Windows can be used as a compute node connected to the controller.

For more information please refer to this link:
https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/373/how-do-you-install-openstack-on-a-windows-pc/